# Interpret several classifications to one classification result

Tags: classification, dataset, model-evaluation, combinatorics

I want to interpret several data series X, that consist of like 4 to 20 values that can range from 1 to 5. Imagine these as a result of classifications, where each row is a different id, and each element in the series is another estimation in time of the id. The series has the numerical classes(int):1,2,3,4,5; these describe the amount of people in a room. The class can change too.

This sounds like an easy task at first, but it isn’t that easy. my goal is

- to find a good way to classify the series
- to have a possibility to also detect class changes (see last rows) and to figure out the position of the class change
- I also want to find out how this science field is called in general and where to find information on that, so I can help myself.
- I don’t want to use ML or regression for that step

[image]

I know that I could reach a so-so estimation already by mean or median, but Im looking forward to find a more complex approach like using a moving average as smoothing before to improve results. However, this might also destroy some structures, see last 3 examples of Smoothing 1.

My considerations to the class change: There is a class change wherever an increase/decrease in the series is AND the change will not turn back with the next value. (eg changes at smoothing type 2, last example: 0 -1 0 -> change is from 2nd to 3rd element, negative). By that I could also detect the position where a change occurs.

I guess there might be be more elegant ways and Im also sure that I am not the first one looking for something like that.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in the same question:
There's a scientific field that handles combination of classifiers.
One tries to figure out 1 class with several classifiers, resulting in several estimations, eg, sample 1 classifies as 3,3, and 3, so I define it as 3 based on some criteria.

Running your classification over different parts of your data, and then combining these is quite similar. I recommend to give this paper a read:

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=8335271